# Select from SQL database information with newest revisions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, revision

I coding web app for my client and have issue with selecting from database raports with newest revisions.

```
SELECT 
        raports.*,
        r1.*,
        users.*, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM changes WHERE changes.changes_raports_id = raports.raports_id) as changes,
        (SELECT changes.changes_date FROM changes WHERE changes.changes_raports_id = raports.raports_id ORDER BY changes.changes_date DESC LIMIT 1) as last_change,
        (SUM(injuries.injuries_min_procent) / COUNT(injuries_to_raports.injuries_to_raports_id)) as min,
        (SUM(injuries.injuries_max_procent) / COUNT(injuries_to_raports.injuries_to_raports_id)) as max
    FROM raports
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.users_id = raports.raports_users_id 
    LEFT JOIN changes 
        ON changes.changes_raports_id = raports.raports_id 
    LEFT JOIN raports_to_changes r1
        ON r1.raports_to_changes_raports_id = raports.raports_id
    LEFT JOIN injuries_to_raports 
        ON injuries_to_raports.injuries_to_raports_raports_id = r1.raports_to_changes_raports_id
    LEFT JOIN injuries
        ON injuries_to_raports.injuries_to_raports_injuries_id = injuries.injuries_id
    WHERE r1.raports_to_changes_changes_id = (SELECT max(raports_to_changes_changes_id) FROM raports_to_changes r2 WHERE r2.raports_to_changes_raports_id = r1.raports_to_changes_raports_id)
    GROUP BY raports.raports_id ORDER BY raports.raports_id ASC;
```

In columns max and min i have not correct average from injuries. When i checked it and count all injuries i had 36 when true number is 2 but i have 18 revisions. So is logic that i have looped COUNT with all revisions but i want only the newest

I try changing WHERE  statements and more LEFT JOINs but nothing helped.

Could someone fixed that code?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: That is quite a JOIN  statement.  You might be on the right track with a LEFT Join but there are other types that give different results, and perhaps you might need one of those to get results you would like.  Check this link out, that site has a pretty good explanation of various types.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: What version of MySQL? This gets a LOT easier and more efficient if you're using 8.0 or later and can use a windowing function to identify the first row instead of correlating to a (SELECT MAX()...) subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clues revealed by your queries, the data model may look like this:

[image: ERD - Injury Report Revisions]

The `select` list shows that you need:

1. `users` information of a `reports_id`
2. aggregated `injuries_min_procent` and `injuries_max_procent` at `raports_id` level. (see `cte_raport_injuries`)
3. number of `changes` of a `raports_id` (see `cte_raport_changes`)
4. the last `change_date` of a `raports_id` (see `cte_raport_changes`)

I'm not sure about the need for `raports_of_changes` based on information revealed in the question, so I'm going to ignore it for now.

```sql
with cte_raport_injuries as (
select r.raports_id,
       sum(i.injuries_min_procent) / count(*) as injuries_min_procent,
       sum(i.injuries_max_procent) / count(*) as injuries_max_procent
  from raports r
  join injuries_to_raports ir
    on r.raports_id = ir.injuries_to_raports_raports_id
  join injuries i
    on ir.injuries_to_raports_injuries_id = i.injuries_id
 group by r.raports_id),
 cte_raport_changes as (
 select r.raports_id,
       count(c.changes_id) as changes, 
       max(c.changes_date) as last_change
  from raports r
  join changes c
   on r.raports_id = c.changes_raports_id
 group by r.raports_id)
select u.users_id,
       r.raports_id,
       ri.injuries_min_procent,
       ri.injuries_max_procent,
       rc.changes,
       rc.last_change
  from raports r
  join users u
    on r.raports_users_id = u.users_id
  join cte_raport_injuries ri
    on r.raports_id = ri.raports_id
  join cte_raport_changes rc
    on r.raports_id = rc.raports_id;
```

The result looks like this:

```
users_id|raports_id|injuries_min_procent|injuries_max_procent|changes|last_change|
--------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-----------+
       1|        11|             15.0000|             25.0000|      2| 2022-12-02|
```

So my question for you is what's in `reports_to_changes` that you need and what's its relationship between others? For further involvement from the community, you may want to share the following information in text format:

- DDLs of each tables (primary key, foreign key, column names & data types)
- Some representable sample data and basic business rules
- Expected output